# Problema al recuperar resultado en método ASYNC en Angular10

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs

Estoy intentando validar contra un servicio REST que verifica el usuario y contraseña. Para ello me he creado un método que he definido como ASYNC para que envuelva el resultado en una promesa, ya que en el método llamador tengo que hacer también otro tipo de tratamientos.

Me está fallando al devolver el resultado del método hacia el método llamador. ¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema sin cambiar la lógica que tengo montada?

Adjunto código:

```
async login(usuario: string, contrasena: string): Promise<UsuaToken> {
    /* Borramos las credenciales que ya pudiera tener el usuario */
    this.borrarCredenciales();
 
    if (typeof(usuario) !== 'string' || typeof(contrasena) !== 'string'){
      // Usuario o contraseña no informados
      return null;
    }
 
    this.http.post(`${environment.url}/usuarios/login`, 
            {usuario: usuario, contrasena: contrasena})
        .subscribe(
          // Comprobamos el usuario y contraseña contra la BBDD
          (resp: any) => {
             this.token = resp.token;
             this.usuConectado = this.decodificarToken(this.token);
             localStorage.setItem("token", this.token);
             console.log("** usuario recuperado: ", this.usuConectado);
             return this.usuConectado;
          },
          (err) => {
             // Se ha producido algún tipo de error
             console.log("** usuario no recuperado (1) ");
             return null
          } 
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Este sería el código para usar una promesa

```
async login(usuario: string, contrasena: string): Promise<any> {
        this.borrarCredenciales();
    
        // el método debe retornar una promesa
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
          //  en lugar de usar return, se debe usar ya sea resolve
          // o reject para devolver valores
          if (typeof usuario !== "string" || typeof contrasena !== "string") {
            // Usuario o contraseña no informados
            resolve(null);
          }
    
         // se hace la petición http
          this.http
            .post(`${environment.url}/usuarios/login`, {
              usuario: usuario,
              contrasena: contrasena
            })
            // en lugar de suscribirse se convierte en una promesa
            .toPromise()
            // cuando la petición finaliza se procesa el resultado
            .then(
              // Comprobamos el usuario y contraseña contra la BBDD
              (resp: any) => {
                this.token = resp.token;
                this.usuConectado = this.decodificarToken(this.token);
                localStorage.setItem("token", this.token);
                console.log("** usuario recuperado: ", this.usuConectado);
                // en lugar de un return se usa resolve para devolver el valor
                resolve(this.usuConectado);
              },
              err => {
                // Se ha producido algún tipo de error
                console.log("** usuario no recuperado (1) ");
                reject(null);
              }
            );
        });
      }
```

Comment: Hola Lobos. Si tienes async en la función no te envolvía el resultado en una promesa resuelta y las excepciones en una promesa reject?

Comment: Si te refieres a `return this.usuConectado;` no, ese retorno es el de la función callback del subscribe() no es el valor de retorno de la función `login`